# Create clickable URL in Hue

Tags: solr, hue

I want to create a clickable URL in hue as shown in below image :

[image]

I found it in a blog :

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-process-and-index-medical-images-with-apache-hadoop-and-apache-solr/

They have not explained how they did it.

Can anyone tell me how can it be done in hue?

Comment: It's just HTML ... `<a href="">text</a>`?

Comment: This page is created using official Apache hue tool. So we can not make clickable URL using html code. I think there should be some option in  hue to do it.But I am not able to find that option.

Comment: Note: It's just Cloudera Hue, not part of the ASF. You might get a better answer on the Hue Google User Groups (or comment on the blog)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found my answer in Hue Google User groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the video,

Drag the HTML results panel onto the dashboard, go to the HTML tab of the Editor, add a field for

```
<a href="{{url}}">text you want to display</a>
```

Where `url` is the field of the collection (the `{{ }}` marks are to be included to render the field)